# how do i upgrade csc to latest roslyn tools

Tags: c#, roslyn

I don't use visual studio, when i compile a .cs file in cmd, even though it says its using version 4.8 it also says its only up to version 5 of C#, how do i update the csc roslyn tools so i can compile with v8?
This is what cmd says

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.3752.0
for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240
```

When i went to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240 i had no idea what to and how to install

Comment: Related: [How to install Roslyn (for use in source-code-modification)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597741/how-to-install-roslyn-for-use-in-source-code-modification)

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis

Comment: Didn't you ask the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334883/why-is-net-framework-v4-8-only-able-to-compile-c-sharp-version-5) already?

Comment: I would download the .NET CLI from here :https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download that will include everything you need to compile code on any operating system

Comment: @DragandDrop i don't use visual studio i cant do Install-package